# YouTube Objective-C API Push Notifications

Tags: ios, ios7, youtube, youtube-api, apple-push-notifications

Does Google provide a way to get push notification on iOS when a new video is uploaded to a playlist?

I found a Google I/O video where they discuss YouTube API push notifications for web apps but I can't find any documentation for iOS push notifications.

https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/328119818

If they do not provide a solution what would be the best options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a request for this, you can track it from public issue tracker.

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5602

Till then, your best option is to poll the server with API request with either constant or exponential backoff in a loop.